# Prove fractional integral at $\alpha = 0$ converges to the original function

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, fractional-calculus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville_integral

Under the properties section, it says $I^{\alpha}f \rightarrow f$ as $\alpha \rightarrow 0.$ But it offers no proof, is there a proof of this somewhere?